# Download a pdf in the selected language

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

First time poster here 
I'm new to web design and I'm making a multilanguage site for product-display purpose, each product has a downloadable .pdf brochure.

I have a pdf file for each language and I wanted to change the link according to the selected language. Is there a way to verify the language using javascript or php?

If you need technic information for the language setting, I made it following this tutorial: 
[here is the link for same](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed that link to the letter you can adjust it by adding new variable for storing link and then generate it as needed, like this:

```
$pdfLink = '';
$downloadText = '';

switch ($lang) {
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  $pdfLink = 'file.en.pdf';
  $downloadText = 'Link for download';
  break;

  case 'de':
  $lang_file = 'lang.de.php';
  $pdfLink = 'file.de.pdf';
  $downloadText = 'Link zum Download';
  break;

  case 'es':
  $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
  $pdfLink = 'file.es.pdf';
  $downloadText = 'Enlace para descargar';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  $pdfLink = 'file.en.pdf';
  $downloadText = 'Link for download';

} // assuming they are all in same folder. If not, add path
```

and later you generate download link similar to this:

```
<a href="path_to_folder_containing_pdfs_for_download/<?php echo $pdfLink; ?>"><?php echo $downloadText;?></a>
```

EDIT:

I used google translate for $downloadText variable so I don't recommend using it really before checking is it correct :)

Comment: I don't fully understand variable storage yet, but this answer taught me that I can use variable to write code and not only showing text. So, in the lang_en.php file i did: $lang['brochure_pdf'] = 'brochure_en.pdf'; And then, in the page: <a herf="../media/<?php echo $lang['brochure_pdf']; ?>">Download</a>. This way works for me.